# <pe:blockUI> does not invoke on <p:remoteCommand> onstart

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to use pe:blockUI on the onstart of a remoteCommand(autoRun="true") but getting javascript errors saying "property block() is undefined for null reference" when "myCommand" is invoked.

```
<h:form>
     <pe:blockUI id="blocker" widgetVar="blocker" />

     <p:remoteCommand name="myCommand" onstart="PF('blocker').block()" 
     oncomplete="PF('blocker').unblock()" autoRun="true"/>
<h:form>
```

I'm using PF 5.3 and PF-extensions 4.0.0.

Any ideas on why this is happening and what could be the solution?

Comment: Do you really need some features of the PrimeFaces extensions' `blockUI`? I also used to get some issues with the `pe:blockUI` component and switch back to `p:blockUI`. (Do not forget to change `.block()` and `.unblock()` by `.show()` and `.hide()`)

Comment: Does your version of PrimeFaces supports `PF('')`?  I would first try using `blocker.block()` and `blocker.unblock()`.

Comment: I would first ask to post version info...  And make sure to tell the OP to **not** use the same value for widgetVar and id

Comment: @Kukeltje I didn't know that conflicts are possible between `id` and `widgetVar`.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: It should not be a problem anymore aiaik with 5.x releases, but better safe

Comment: @kukeltje, I've edited to mention the PF versions.